# how to convert excel columns to one list separted by comma in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Im trying to convert an excel  columns into a dataframe list separated by comma, 
[Here is the excel sheet](https://ibb.co/wpFP80f)

that is the code I'm trying:

```
df=pd.read_excel('eng_test.xlsx',"Sheet1")
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df) 
for column in new_df:
    new_df2=new_df.apply(pd.Series)
    new_df3=(new_df2.to_string())
    new_df4=new_df3.split()
#print(new_df4)
```

I' m expecting the df be like this 
`df = pd.DataFrame(['This is my first sentence', 'This is a second sentence with more words'])`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `list(df.columns)` would create a list with the names of the columns in `df`

Comment: To be clear, you need to convert your excel column to dataframe or a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not clear what you really what to achieve a Dataframe with rows from Excel column or a list, you can do something like this using `header=None`:

```
df=pd.read_excel('text_excel.xlsx', header=None)
print("\nDataframe: ")
print(df)
df_list = df.values.tolist()
print("\nList: ")
print(df_list)
```

With this you get the following output:

```
Dataframe: 
                                           0
0                'This is my first sentence'
1  This is a second sentence with more words

List: 
[["'This is my first sentence'"], ['This is a second sentence with more words']]
```

Comment: will do for sure when my reputation gets to 15 coz I cant when its less than that sorry. but be sure will do that